# Javascript: how to loop through the list to find the active class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i have several `<li id="imgXXX"></li>` , and i want to create a function so that it will accept a parameter as `id` and checks all the `<li id="img..."></li>`  for matching the id number , where ever it will find the matching `id` with the `li` then there it will add a css class named as `<li id="img233" class='activeImage'></li>`  And also removes other active class in the list if exists.

```
<div class="jcarousel-clip jcarousel-clip-horizontal" style="position: relative;">
         <ul id="second-carousel" class="first-and-second-carousel jcarousel-list jcarousel-list-horizontal"  >

         <li id="img233">
                <img  src=""></img>
         </li>
          <li id="img234">
                <img  src=""></img>
         </li>
         <li id="img235">
                <img  src=""></img>
         </li>
          <li id="img236">
                <img  src=""></img>
         </li>  

       </ul>
</div
```

Suppose i passed `233` as id parameter then how can i add this active class on the above list with matching id

```
function addactive(id)
{
  $("#second-carousel").each(function()
   {
     $(this).closest("li #img"+id).addClass("activeImage");
   });
}
```

//the above function ,i tried as a dummy solution,But it did not solve my problem. Please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder yeah it is unique, only i just shows you one <li> . Please read my example , there is all the id different.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder from what I understand OP meant `imgxxx`

Comment: @T.J.Crowder sorry about that...

Answer (score 2):

There is no need for iteration, it can be done by using only selectors

```
function addactive(id) {
    $("#second-carousel li.activeImage").removeClass('activeImage');
    $("#img"+id).addClass("activeImage");
}
```

Comment: thanks, let me try, i will inform you after implementing it with my project

Comment: I see there is already dynamically a class is rendering to `<li id="imgXXX"></li>`  so i can not use this `$("#second-carousel li.activeImage").removeClass('activeImage');` is there any way to show `active` link using this css/jquery way to my `li`?